# Avoiding exceptions while violating a validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not really experienced at Ruby on Rails so I need your help.

**Visit.rb**

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to          :employee
    belongs_to          :visitor
    default_scope   ->  { order(:created_at) }

    validates   :start,           presence: true,     uniqueness: {scope: [:end, :visitor_id]}
    validates   :end,             presence: true
    validates   :visitor_id,      presence: true
    validates   :employee_id,     presence: true
    validate    :valid_date_range_required

    def valid_date_range_required
        if (start && end) && (end < start)
            errors.add(:end, "must be after start")
        end
    end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "visits", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
    t.date     "start"
    t.date     "end"
    t.integer  "idVisit"
    t.integer  "employee_id"
    t.integer  "visitor_id"
    t.string   "status",      default: "Confirmed"
  end

  add_index "visits", ["start", "end", "visitor_id"], name: "index_visits_on_start_and_end_and_visitor_id", unique: true
```

During my tests, if I violate validation on uniqueness or on :valid_date_range_required my application raises a sort of exception blocking itself (for example: *First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty*). Instead I wouldn't want the application to show it, but I would want the application to show a sort of error message during the creation of the Visit so that the user can fill the form in an appropriate way.

May someone of you help me to understand a way to do it?

**EDIT:**

**visits_controller.rb**

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_employee,  only: [:create,    :destroy]
    before_action :correct_employee,    only: [:destroy,   :update ]

    def create
        @visit = current_employee.visits.build(visit_params)
        if @visit.save
            flash[:success] = "Visit added"
            redirect_to employee_path(session[:employee_id], :act => 'guestsVisits')
        else
            @visits = current_employee.visits.all
            @employee = current_employee
            @errors = @visit.errors.full_messages
            flash[:danger] = @errors
            render 'employees/guestsVisits'
        end
    end



    private

        def visit_params
            params.require(:visit).permit(:start, :end, :visitor_id, :employee_id)
        end
end
```

**guestsVisits.rb** (my view)

```
<div class="jumbotron3 text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Guests Visits</h1>
    <hr>
    <%=render :partial =>"layouts/sidebar"%>
    <div class="panel3">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <% if logged_in? %>
                <%=render :partial =>"shared/error_messages"%>

                  <a class="btn icon-btn btn-success pos" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#visitModal">
                <span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-plus img-circle text-success"></span>
                Add a visit
                </a>

                <div id="visitModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add a visit</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                <%= form_for(@visit) do |f| %>

                <%= f.label :start_date %>
                <%= f.date_field :start, class: 'form-control',:value => (f.object.start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if f.object.start) %>
                <%= errors_for @visit, :start %><%if @visit.errors.any?%><br><%end%>

                <br>
                <%= f.label :end_date %>
                <%= f.date_field :end, class: 'form-control',:value => (f.object.end.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if f.object.end) %>
                <%= errors_for @visit, :end %><%if @visit.errors.any?%><br><%end%>

                <br>
                <%= f.label :Visitor %>
                <%= f.collection_select :visitor_id, Visitor.all, :id, :full_name, { :class=> "form-control", :include_blank => ''}%>
                <%= errors_for @visit, :visitor_id %><%if @visit.errors.any?%><br><%end%>
                <br>
                <%= f.submit "Add visit", class: "btn btn-primary btn-color" %>
                <% end %>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <% end %>
                </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**error_messages.rb**

```
<% if @visit && @visit.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@visit.errors.count, "error") %>.Open the modal for more details
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What I need is that, adding the end date which comes before the start date or adding a record (start, end, visitor) which is already in the database, I can show the error in my modal without blocking all the application because of *First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty* exception or similar.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: can you post the test?

Comment: Your controller should be handling this. Are you using erb templates to render your creation pages or a custom page? Templates generated by rails will automatically render model errors over fields which are failing validations. You test should just confirm an exception is raised on an invalid model assignment.

Comment: I have a modal containing a form to create a visit. I would like that if I choose an end date which comes before the start date or if I try to create a visit having the same start, end and visitor of another already saved in the db, after clicking the button to create it, an error in the modal shows up explaining the problem instead of an exception blocking everything, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could create a custom message for errors relating to uniqueness.

```
validates   :start, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: [:end, :visitor_id],    
message: ->(object, data) do 'Each start can only have one visitor and one end.' 
end
}

 class VisitsController

   def create 
     @visit = Visit.find(params[:id])
     if @visit.save
       flash.now[:success] = 'Visit created' 
       redirect_to @visit
     else
       @errors = @visit.errors.full_messages
       flash[:danger] = @errors
       redirect_to root_url 
     end 
   end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Comment: It's often better to use `save!` and then `rescue` any exceptions that might have failed. Also, when linking to the documentation, try to get the current version and not a historical one.

Comment: Even doing like this, the exception occurs and blocks everything.

Comment: @AnM I think you have to post view and controller.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss I added everything, I hope you can have a look to it. Thank you a lot for your help.